# Kotlin apply function with data class

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I have a data class like this -

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String)
```

I want to use `apply` scope function to modify the values and return the modified object.

```
User("1", "Name").apply {
   this.id = "2" // Gives me error since val cannot be assigned
}
```

I do not want to make my data class immutable and also don't want to use `copy` function. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `copy` method with `data` classes:

```
val user1 = User("1", "Name")
val user2 = user1.copy(id = "2")
```

Comment: Yes with copy I could do I know but is there no possibility with apply?

Comment: `User("1", "Name").apply { copy(id = "2") }` ? I don't understand why do you need `apply` and why don't you want to use `copy` method?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

change like this `data class User(var id: String, var name: String)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28094979)

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko In what way isn't this an answer to the question. Although code-only answers without an explanation are frowned upon, they are still an answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Of course, you are right. This does not mean that the proposed code cannot solve the issue. Now it is useful, but just a comment. Some explanation needed to improve the answer: why the error occurs, why the proposed solution solves the issue, etc. And there is not other appropriate option in Review Form.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko There is no suitable option in the review for because this an answer, and therefor should not be voted to be deleted. If you think an answer is bad, downvoting is the correct response.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think that this answer is bad: I'm think that it is very good and useful, but it is really a comment. Anyway, thanks for explanation I will change my approach to answers like that.